# Groupby is not finding all id's

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Groupby isnt finding all id's

- I extracted id's from a url's
- Put all in dataframe
- when I group by, it just find few id's
- then I added `cw["campaignid"] = cw["campaignid"].str.replace(r'\ ', '')`  to remove spaces, even so doesnt find the id's

Data frame

```
cw=

campaignid    name    isb    

11            aaa     true
11            asa     false
11            afs     true
45            adfs    false
45            ads     true
```

my attempt

```
cw["campaignid"] = cw["campaignid"].str.replace(r'\ ', '')

grouped_cw = cw.groupby(["campaignid"]).sum()

grouped_cw.rename(columns={'isb':'leads'}, inplace=True)

grouped_cw = pd.DataFrame(grouped_cw)
```

output

```
campaignid    leads

11            2
45            2
```

Desired output

```
campaignid    leads

11            3
45            2
```

Comment: Use `count()` instead of `sum()`. False is being treated like a 0 while True is being treated like a 1. `count()` will give you desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is get a record count by `campaignid`.  So use `.count()` instead of `.sum()`

see below:

```
grouped = cw.groupby(["campaignid"]).count()
grouped['leads'] = grouped['name']
grouped.drop(['name','isb'],axis=1, inplace=True)
print(grouped)
```

This gives the desired output you showed in your post.